# Which seek mode in python is used to write without overwriting?

Tags: python

This is my code

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r")
a = fo.readlines();
fo1 = open("write.txt", "w")
j=len(a)
print j
i=0


while i < j:

    if (a[i] == "hi\n" ): 

      fo1.write('hi\nhow\nare\nyou');

       if (a[i] == "hello\n" ): 

        fo1.seek(-3, 2)
        fo1.write('\nalways\nnot\n');

         i += 1


         fo.close()
         fo1.close()
```

There are two text files

1) foo.txt - Contains

```
hi
hello
```

2) write.txt is blank file

It checks a[i] with hello , as it is hello, it will execute this statement of code

```
fo1.write('hi\nhow\nare\nyou');
```

So , write.txt will be like this

```
how
are
you
```

After that it checks it has a[i] is hi
as it is hi, it will move the pointer from end to -3 and will write this code statement

```
fo1.write('\nalways\nnot\n');
```

**The output should be like**

```
How
are
always
not
you
```

But the **current output i get is**

```
How
are
always
not
```

The above output has got 'you' removed
**THe expected output is this**

```
How
are
always
not
you
```

I did tried append and write mode, both does the same

SO, how can i write without overwriting ?

Comment: Despite what you might expect from your experiences with text editors and Microsoft Word, there's no "insert mode" for file writing.

Comment: Indeed, your best hope is to cache the bottom part of the document, add your new text, and paste it again. However this would be slow on large files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are expecting writes to be *inserted* at the current position.  When you set the file position, it will start writing at that position and overwrite the data.

To prevent overwrites, you need to re-write the data after the data you're writing

```
fo1.seek(-3, 2)
end_data = fo1.read()
fo1.seek(-3, 2)
fo1.write('\nalways\nnot\n')
fo1.write(end_data)
```

Also, you don't need to use semi-colons in python.